# Query after connecting to remote MySQL database using mysqli_real_connect

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

I can successfully connect to a remote MySQL database using mysqli_init(), mysqli_ssl_set and mysqlii_real_connect. I can't seem to find an example of a query being done after connecting. The result of mysqli_real_connect is a boolean value, whereas mysqli_connect returns an object representing the connection to the MySQL server. How do I refer to the connection after using mysqli_real_connect? Can anyone provide an example?

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
$obj = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($obj, MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
mysqli_ssl_set( $obj,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                'ca-cert.pem',
                NULL,
                NULL);
$link = mysqli_real_connect($obj, 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.com', 'user', 'password, 'database_name');
if (!$link)
{
    die('<br /><br />Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '.mysqli_connect_error());
} ?>
```

Comment: See the manpage for [`mysqli_real_connect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php) then. Your `$obj` is already the link.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you'd do it using your example is `mysqli_query($obj, QUERY HERE);`

However, you should consider using the OOP (Object Orientated Programming) style, as that would be easier for you to reference within the future.

```
<?php

Class Database {
      private $obj;

      public function __construct() {
          $this->obj = new mysqli('xxxxxxxxxxxx.com', 'user', 'password', 'database_name');
          if (!$this->obj) {
        die('<br /><br />Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '.mysqli_connect_error());
          }
      }

      public function query($query) {
          return  $this->obj->query($query);
      }
} 

?>
```

You would call this class by doing:

```
$db = new Database();
```

And from there on, you could simply call your function by using the following example.

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM users"); // or whatever query you are parsing.
```